# The element <strong> in HTML is deprecated?

Tags: html

I want to know if the element  in HTML5 is deprecated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: nope [<strong>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong).

Comment: strong isn't deprecate in html5 [strong documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strong.asp), but exists a difference between html4 and html5 "In HTML 4.01, the strong tag defines strong emphasized text, but in HTML5 it defines important text."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The  tag is a phrase tag. It defines important text.

Tip: This tag is not deprecated, but it is possible to achieve richer effect with CSS.

In HTML 4.01, the  tag defines strong emphasized text, but in HTML5 it defines important text.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strong.asp

Comment: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/strong.html) would probably be a better reference than w3schools...

Comment: @AlexShesterov   - The result is the same any way. (no zapomniy ;) )